# How do I make \infty work with eulerpx?

Tags: fonts, math-fonts

I've been dipping my toes into the realm of playing with fonts in LaTeX. I got my text fonts working great, but when I decided to try the math fonts, I went with [eulerpx](https://ctan.org/pkg/eulerpx?lang=en). It looks great, but doesn't want to render a lemniscate when I use the `\infty` command. Basically, I used

```
    \usepackage{eulerpx}

    \((-\infty, 0) , (0,\infty) \)
```

I don't get any errors, but when it renders, I get:

[image]

without the infinity symbols. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome! Please post compilable code rather than fragments. I can guarantee that the code you've posted *will* give errors if used as provided. Do you get warnings? Presumably, the font doesn't have that symbol.

Comment: If you can't update, a temporary workaround is to add `\DeclareMathSymbol{\infty}{\mathord}{symbols}{49}` to your document preamble, just before `\begin{document}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to update your TeX distribution in order to get the current version of `eulerpx`.

As the README provided at the link you posted states"

> 2017-04-10:
>
> v0.2.1: Fixed a bug that prevented `\infty` from displaying correctly.
>
> [Thanks to Georg Bube for reporting the problem and solution.]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{eulerpx}

\begin{document}

\((-\infty, 0) , (0,\infty) \)


\end{document}
```

[image: current infinities]